¿porque mi panel de usuario no se puede ver en mi localhost?
tengo un proyecto que es un panel de usuario con algunas opciones de modificar y agregar usuario, este está hecho basado en MVC con codelgniter, tengo el codigo listo, pero no sé si funciona pues al intentar verlo en localhost no me deja, me aparece error 404, ya intenté muchas rutas y ninguna me funciona, les comparto mi codigo.
este es user_panel.php que está en la carpeta de views dentro de la de aplicaciones en mi carpeta llamada proyecto
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
 <style>
 </style>


<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Panel de Usuario</title>
   </head>
     <body>
<div>
    <h1>Panel de Usuario</h1>
    <div>
        <h2>Agregar Usuario</h2>
        <form action="<?php echo base_url('user/add_user'); ?>" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name">
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
            <button type="submit">Agregar</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h2>Editar Usuario</h2>
        <form id="editForm" action="<?php echo base_url('user/edit_user'); ?>" 
      method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="id" id="editId">
            <input type="text" name="name" id="editName" placeholder="Name">
            <input type="email" name="email" id="editEmail" placeholder="Email">
            <button type="submit">Guardar cambios</button>
        </form>
     </div>
      <div>
        <h2>Lista de Usuario</h2>
        <ul>
            <?php foreach ($users as $user): ?>
                <li><?php echo $user->name; ?> - <?php echo $user->email; ?> 
                    <button onclick="fillEditForm('<?php echo $user->id; ?>', '<?php 
        echo $user->name; ?>', '<?php echo $user->email; ?>')">Editar</button>
                    <form style="display: inline-block;" action="<?php echo 
      base_url('user/delete_user'); ?>" method="post">
                        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $user->id; ? 
     >">
                        <button type="submit">Eliminar</button>
                    </form>
                </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
          <script>
       function fillEditForm(id, name, email) {
        document.getElementById('editId').value = id;
        document.getElementById('editName').value = name;
        document.getElementById('editEmail').value = email;
    }
        </script>
      </body>
        </html>

La siguiente es User.php que está en controller dentro de app y de proyecto
  <?php

      class User extends CI_Controller {

      public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('user_model');
     }

       public function index() {
    $data['users'] = $this->user_model->get_users();
    $this->load->view('user_panel', $data);
     }

         public function add_user() {
    $name = $this->input->post('name');
    $email = $this->input->post('email');
    $this->user_model->add_user($name, $email);
    redirect('user');
         }

        public function edit_user() {
    $id = $this->input->post('id');
    $name = $this->input->post('name');
    $email = $this->input->post('email');
    $this->user_model->edit_user($id, $name, $email);
    redirect('user');
       }

       public function delete_user() {
    $id = $this->input->post('id');
    $this->user_model->delete_user($id);
    redirect('user');
       }
        }

y por ultimo User_model.php que esta en models dentro de app y proyecto
     <?php


       class User_model extends CI_Model {

      public function get_users() {
       return $this->db->get('users')->result();
        }

         public function add_user($name, $email) {
          $data = array(
        'name' => $name,
        'email' => $email
            );
           $this->db->insert('users', $data);
           }

          public function edit_user($id, $name, $email) {
              $data = array(
        'name' => $name,
        'email' => $email
               );
              $this->db->where('id', $id);
            $this->db->update('users', $data);
               }

               public function delete_user($id) {
           $this->db->where('id', $id);
             $this->db->delete('users');
          }
           }

el nombre de mi database es user_panel_db, cuando entro a la ruta Localhost/proyecto/public/ solo me sale lo de bienvenida, y cuando intento agregar el user,User,user_panel o hasta index.php me sale error 404 page not found.


Verifica la configuración de tu archivo .htaccess: En CodeIgniter, es común utilizar un archivo .htaccess para gestionar las URL amigables. Asegúrate de que este archivo esté configurado correctamente para que las rutas se manejen adecuadamente.

Revisa la configuración de las rutas en CodeIgniter: Como mencioné anteriormente, las rutas se definen en el archivo routes.php. Asegúrate de que las rutas estén configuradas correctamente para que las URL se correspondan con los controladores y métodos adecuados.

Verifica la estructura de directorios: Es importante asegurarse de que la estructura de directorios en tu proyecto CodeIgniter esté configurada de acuerdo con las convenciones del framework. Asegúrate de que los archivos estén en las carpetas correctas (por ejemplo, los controladores en la carpeta controllers, las vistas en la carpeta views, etc.).

Comprueba la configuración de la base de datos: Si tu proyecto interactúa con una base de datos, asegúrate de que la configuración de la base de datos en database.php dentro de la carpeta application/config sea correcta.


